# snakemake substitution issue

Tags: snakemake

I am new to snakemake and have an issue with the following code that should take 9 fastq files one after another and apply fastqc.

smp should take the values:

UG1_S12
UG2_S13
UG3_S14
UR1_S1
UR2_S2
UR3_S3
UY1_S6
UY2_S7
UY3_S8

Which works when I run

```
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("reads/merged_s{smp}_L001.fastq.gz")
NB_SAMPLES = len(SAMPLES)

for smp in SAMPLES:
  message("Sample " + smp + " will be processed")
message("N= " + str(NB_SAMPLES))
```

The problem is the replacement of {smp} below which is first replaced by UY2_S7 then by UY3_S8 in the mv commands.

How should I make sure that the same substitution is used in both subcommands of the same rule?

my current code ([inspired by](http://pedagogix-tagc.univ-mrs.fr/courses/ABD/practical/snakemake/snake_intro.html))):

```
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("reads/merged_s{smp}_L001.fastq.gz")

rule all: 
  input: 
        expand("reads/merged_s{smp}_L001.fastq.gz", smp=SAMPLES),
        "results/multiqc.html"

rule fastqc:
    """
    Run FastQC on each FASTQ file.
    """
    input:
        "reads/merged_s{smp}_L001.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "results/{smp}_fastqc.html",
        "intermediate/{smp}_fastqc.zip"
    version: "1.0"
    shadow: "minimal"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        """
        # Run fastQC and save the output to the current directory
        fastqc {input} -t {threads} -q -d . -o .

        # Move the files which are used in the workflow
        mv merged_s{smp}_L001_fastqc.html {output[0]}
        mv merged_s{smp}_L001_fastqc.zip {output[1]}
        """
```

the error:

```
Error in rule fastqc:
    jobid: 0
    output: results/UY2_S7_fastqc.html, intermediate/UY2_S7_fastqc.zip

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 60 of Snakefile:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  
        # Run fastQC and save the output to the current directory
        fastqc reads/merged_sUY2_S7_L001.fastq.gz -t 8 -q -d . -o .

        # Move the files which are used in the workflow
        mv merged_sUY3_S8_L001_fastqc.html results/UY2_S7_fastqc.html
        mv merged_sUY3_S8_L001_fastqc.zip intermediate/UY2_S7_fastqc.zip ' returned non-zero exit status 130.
  File "Snakefile", line 60, in __rule_fastqc
  File "/opt/biotools/miniconda2/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the wildcards in the shell command, you have to use `{wildcards.smp}` .
What is probably happening is that `{smp}` in the shell command takes the value of the last iteration of the for loop above.  So change:

```
shell:
    """
    # Run fastQC and save the output to the current directory
    fastqc {input} -t {threads} -q -d . -o .

    # Move the files which are used in the workflow
    mv merged_s{smp}_L001_fastqc.html {output[0]}
    mv merged_s{smp}_L001_fastqc.zip {output[1]}
    """
```

into:

```
shell:
    """
    # Run fastQC and save the output to the current directory
    fastqc {input} -t {threads} -q -d . -o .

    # Move the files which are used in the workflow
    mv merged_s{wildcards.smp}_L001_fastqc.html {output[0]}
    mv merged_s{wildcards.smp}_L001_fastqc.zip {output[1]}
    """
```

I have not checked the rest of the code.

Comment: thanks a lot, it does it. I have to understand how wildcards work and reread the tutorial once more

Comment: Yep, it is pretty easy to understand. Note that you can directly generate your fastqc results into the directory of your choice instead of generating them in the working directory to move them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it starts to become more clear. I move the files to two different places so I think I cannot do that with the direct command which only takes a base folder as prefix for both files.

Comment: @splaisan Ah yes indeed, I had not seen that in your code ^^ !!